# No module type named 'ExtUpperEthernetInterface' while running the showase/videostreaming

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to run the videostreaming showcase example in INET. Running the run.sh script outputs the following error:

<!> Error: Submodule eth: No module type named 'ExtUpperEthernetInterface' found that implements module interface inet.linklayer.contract.IEthernetInterface (not in the loaded NED files?), at /home/belal/projects/inet/src/inet/node/base/LinkLayerNodeBase.ned:93 -- in module (inet::NodeBase) VideoStreamingShowcase.host1 (id=7), during network setup

End.

I built the INET framework with make, cd to the videostreaming showcase and run the setup and run scripts. I expected the simulation to start but an error occured.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. INET must be compiled with emulation features enabled. These are disabled by default.